# Visual C++ - MFC how to change disablity of a button using edit box

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm currently working with MFC, and I want to make a simple account managment.

I made a login button which is set to disabled from the start and 2 edit box which each one of them is a user id and a password.

I want to make a simple thing : if one of the edit box has no value at all then make the loggin button disabled, else..make the button available.

However, the code doesn't work at all.

this is the code :

part of the header file

```
 // Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
private:
    // Value of the "Username" textbox
    CString m_CStr_UserID;
    // Control variable of the "Username" textbox
    CEdit m_CEdit_ID;
    // Value of the "Password" textbox
    CString m_CStr_UserPass;
    // Control variable of the "Password" textbox
    CEdit m_CEdit_PASS;
    // Control variable of the "Login" button
    CButton m_Btn_Login;
public:
    afx_msg void OnEnChangeEditId();

    afx_msg void OnEnChangeEditPass();
```

proceed to the .cpp

```
 .....
void CTestDlg::OnEnChangeEditId()
{
    // TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
    // send this notification unless you override the CDialog::OnInitDialog()
    // function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
    // with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.

    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here

    m_CEdit_ID.GetWindowTextW(m_CStr_UserID);
    if(!m_CStr_UserID.IsEmpty() && !m_CStr_UserPass.IsEmpty())
        m_Btn_Login.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_Btn_Login.EnableWindow(FALSE);
}

void CTestDlg::OnEnChangeEditPass()
{
    // TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
    // send this notification unless you override the CDialog::OnInitDialog()
    // function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
    // with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.

    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here
    m_CEdit_PASS.GetWindowTextW(m_CStr_UserPass);
    if(!m_CStr_UserPass.IsEmpty() && !m_CStr_UserID.IsEmpty())
        m_Btn_Login.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    m_Btn_Login.EnableWindow(FALSE);
}
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both handlers it's always being enabled FALSE. I think you're missing an `else`

You either need to `return` after the EnableWindow(TRUE) or use an `else`.

Comment: acraig5057, thank you so much.
I feel so ashamed that this "else" was the problem, I alway knew that when executing an if phrase you can do a one line in the condition without an else because it will skip to the next line in case it wont work.
anyway, this "else" solved my issue, I'll keep that in mind. thanks alot!

Comment: @HarelM Be aware that un-accepting an answer makes that person lose the 15 rep points, so always be certain that the new accept is worth it.

Comment: I didn't knew it. sorry.
When I saw I can only give the accetion for one question I gave it back to you. You were the first and you deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

acraig5057 explained the problem with your code and showed you how to work around it. I will just add that you can also do this: map the EN_CHANGE for both edit controls to one handler, let's call it OnEnChangeEditIdOrPass:

```
void CTestDlg::OnEnChangeEditIdOrPass()
{        
    m_Btn_Login.EnableWindow((m_CEdit_ID.GetWindowTextLength() != 0) && 
                             (m_CEdit_PASS.GetWindowTextLength() != 0));
}
```

The function `GetWindowTextLength` returns the number of characters in the specified edit control and 0 if the edit control is empty.

The logic of the above code is this: if both the edit boxes have characters in them, the && will return `TRUE` and the login button will be enabled. If at least one of them does not, the && will return `FALSE` and the login button will be disabled.

Of course, this code *not* save the values of the username and the password edit controls into string variables, like your code does, but you can always call GetWindowText from inside the handler of the login button.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't knew about that.